# unix command to find directories/files which occupies more space

Tags: unix

My server is running out of space. I am logged in to the shell, and I'm trying to find which directory/files are occupying more space.

Is there any unix command which will display the largest files/folders (which occupies more space on the server)?

Thanks,
Dora

Comment: Dora, if either of our answers was useful, it would be good etiquette to accept the one that served your purpose. And if both miss your point, to let it be known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Display free space for drive/mount point

```
df -hk
```

#### Display space occupied by each directory under specific path

```
du -ksh /nfs/backup/*
```

#### Find files/dir greater than specific size

```
find /nfs/backup/* -size +10000k -print | xargs ls -sd
```

some versions of UNIX flavors do not accept human readable size notations, then you can use below command

```
 find /nfs/backup/* -size +1048576 -exec ls -lh {} \;
```